# How can I determine the total size of a QIODevice for read?

Tags: c++, qt, qiodevice

I'm using qt 5.3.

I have a big thing written into a QIODevice for read. I want to have a proxy to get the data while keep the data in QIODevice available for the other thing to read. So if I call readAll() I will get everything good in proxy but the other reader cannot get any data.

I think I should use peek() but this seems requires a maxsize. I tried for passing size() or bytesAvailable() but they didn't get me the real size. They returns probably a buffer size of some weird value as 3287. But my data is as huge as 1081530 bytes.

How can I get the true size of my QIODevice for read?

Edit: The QIODevice I mensioned above is actually QNetworkReply. I want to create a proxy to observe request and response data of my program with a QWebView to access some flash games. I implemented createRequest of my subclass of QNetworkAccessManager and the thing I want to analyze is which I catched through finished() signal of a reply from createRequest.

Edit2: I notice that this QIODevice is a sequential one so the size is unknown. But how to read the data without clearing it?

Comment: When you read the data store it in a `QMap` or `QHash` or else where, is that possible in your situation?

Comment: No, once read, the data will be cleared. Howver, other qt functions, not mine, will try to read the data after I read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QIODevice::seek` and then read the data again
from `seek` documantion:

> For random-access devices, this function sets the current position to
>   pos, returning true on success, or false if an error occurred. For
>   sequential devices, the default behavior is to do nothing and return
>   false.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.
    QByteArray readAll() {
        QByteArray retVal(first, len);
        clear();
        return retVal;
    }

Comment: I don't know why but it clears the byte array after readAll() is called. This piece of code is from qiodevice_p.h

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the size of the content directly from the `QNetworkReply` header using Qt like this:

```
qlonglong size = reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toLongLong();
```

And then use that size with the `peek` function, example:

```
void DownloadManager::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if (!reply->error())
    {
        bool ok;
        qlonglong size = reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toLongLong(&ok);

        if (ok)
        {
            QByteArray data = reply->peek(size); //Here lives your data without reset the internal buffer
            //Do something
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Could not read the header";
        }
    }

    //If you are ready then delete
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```